# How to show the trajectory of a projectile using python?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to stack overflow and programming on the whole, so I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked or is a stupid question on the whole. 
How could I visually show the trajectory of a projectile after doing the calculations in python? Like a module? PyGame? Are there other languages that would be better for this? Thanks,

Nimrodian.

Comment: Language is fairly irrelevant for this. All you need is a UI library/toolkit that allows you to draw your trajectory. How exactly that is done depends on the library/toolkit you use (please use google to find one in your language of choice)

Answer (score 2):

You can use whatever graphic module you'd like.

Pygame is one, right, but I believe matplotlib is probably simpler.

Check this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches

verts = [
    (0., 0.),  # P0
    (0.2, 1.), # P1
    (1., 0.8), # P2
    (0.8, 0.), # P3
    ]

codes = [Path.MOVETO,
         Path.CURVE4,
         Path.CURVE4,
         Path.CURVE4,
         ]

path = Path(verts, codes)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='none', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(patch)

xs, ys = zip(*verts)
ax.plot(xs, ys, 'x--', lw=2, color='black', ms=10)

ax.text(-0.05, -0.05, 'P0')
ax.text(0.15, 1.05, 'P1')
ax.text(1.05, 0.85, 'P2')
ax.text(0.85, -0.05, 'P3')

ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 1.1)
ax.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1)
plt.show()
```

[image: http://matplotlib.org/_images/path_tutorial-2.png]

Taken from : http://matplotlib.org/users/path_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I suggest matplotlib. Here's [a tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).